# How to make a loading mask for a portion of a page in angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a $http request that loads information for a <select> tag.  I want to show some kind of loading mask/image, but I want it to only display over the affected part of the page.

HTML

```
<select ng-model='widgetType' ng-options="widget.name for widget in allWidgets track by widget.id">
<fieldset id="needs-loading-mask" ng-disabled="widgetType.id">
  <div z-index=100 ng-if="loadingVariants"><img src="img/loading.gif" /></div>
  <select ng-model='widgetVariant' ng-optoins="variant.name for variant in allVariants track by variant.id>
<fieldset>
```

JS

```
    $scope.$watch('widgetType.id', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue) {
            $scope.loadingVariants = true;
            console.log("Getting variants from server");
            $timeout(function() { // only here for debug purposes
                $http.get('/api/widget-variants/?widget=' + newValue)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.allVariants = data;
                        $scope.loadingvariants = false;
                    }).error(function (data) {
                        $scope.loadingvariants = false;
                    });
                }, 1000);
        } else {
            $scope.allVariants = [];
        }
    });
```

I'm wanting `#needs-loading-mask` to be occluded by a loading mask while $scope.loadingVariants is true, but I can't figure out how to get it to float OVER the select, filling the parent fieldset using a declarative syntax.

I can't remove the select field because that plays havoc with tab order, but it seems like it should be possible to float something in front of it.

Comment: See the comments in the accepted answer for the bulk of what this question was about.  The answer has sufficient good content that I didn't want to delete the question, but the CSS portion of it is answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027514/how-do-i-mask-a-region-of-the-page-in-a-responsive-design-using-css

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### `$http` is aware of its job

Easy way, with only one boolean management:

Declare a service like this:

```
angular.module('services.httpRequestTracker', [])
    .factory('httpRequestTracker', ['$http', function ($http) {

        var httpRequestTracker = {};
        httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests = function () {
            return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
        };

        return httpRequestTracker;
    }]);
```

In your main controller (usually app controller):

```
$scope.hasPendingRequests = function () {
   return httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests();
};
```

And wherever you want in your page, something like:

```
<div z-index=100 ng-show="hasPendingRequests()><img src="img/loading.gif" /></div>
```

The magic here is thus the `http.pendingRequests.length method`.

Comment: That is a much cleaner version than mine, but how do you get the image up and over the fieldset?  JQuery wise you would measure the fieldset and then position the element over the top of it (I think).  Is there some CSS positioning trick I can use to make that happen here?  I could maybe give it a loading background with css, but I'd rather have a loading foreground.

Comment: The answer had to come in two parts.  This is how you do the CSS to get the localized masking (which was the original question).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027514/how-do-i-mask-a-region-of-the-page-in-a-responsive-design-using-css

Comment: The service definition is unnecessary. You can just "return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0" in the $scope function.

Answer (score 0):

Request Tracker in angulajs.

```
angular.module('services.httpRequestTracker', [])
.service('httpRequestTracker', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var httpRequestTracker = {};
    httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests = function () {
        return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
    };

    return httpRequestTracker;
}]);
```