# How do I mask a region of the page in a responsive design using CSS?

Tags: css

I have multiple areas of the page that are loading asynchronously due to user interaction.  Instead of doing it like hhgregg.com and masking the whole page, I want to mask just the region that is loading.

```
<div id="A">Loaded by Xhr</div>
<div id="B">Loaded by xhr based on actions with A</div>
<div id="C">Loaded by xhr based on action within B</div>
```

Those regions are sized based on screen resolution and therefor I can't just set an absolute position to "mask" with a loading gif.

How do I style a loading mask in CSS so that it covers the div where the loading is taking place.  I can get the loading mask on the page, what I can't figure is how to fill the div I want and only that div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dwabU/1/

All you need to do is to add a class of `masked` to the `DIV` that you want to mask.

CSS:

```
div.masked {
    position: relative;
}

div.masked:before {
    position:absolute;
    content: "MASKED CONTENT";
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.7);
    z-index:1;
    color: #ff0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="A">Loaded by Xhr</div>
<div id="B" class="masked">Loaded by xhr based on actions with A</div>
<div id="C">Loaded by xhr based on action within B</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted

Comment: @Mark0978 Glad to be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

In your xhr script it should give the loading div a class of `loading` then your css should have

```
.loading{
background-image:url(loading.gif);
background-size:contain;
}
```

Comment: Will a background image "cover" the `<div>`? the size is good to make sure it encompasses the entire area, but what if something already exists inside that tag?

Comment: `opacity: .5` usually does a nice job for me in such a case.

Comment: You could also add another entry, `.loading * { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

You set a `position:relative` to each div you want to cover. Then you use pseudo-elements for each, to cover until de ajax is loading the content.
For example: 
`#A{position:relative;}`
`#A:before{content:""; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:black;display:none;}`
While de ajax is loading, you set this element to `display:block`, when the content is loaded, you hide the pseudo-element.